# Logon to remote server using powershell

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0, remote-server, remote-desktop

Experts!

Is there any way to login to remote machines using powershell script earlier i tried with RDP automation but stuck with legal notice banner, my ultimate goal for login remote server using powershell is to make my entry in the server and it should reflect in available when checking reports for last logon users in server, i tried with establishing pssession but it doesn't show my entry.

Any ideas really helpful!! Thanks in advance

Comment: Logging in to a remote server with PowerShell Remoting is easy - but it's a network logon type, so it'll never be reflected in the audit logs or by the desktop session manager as an interactive logon

Comment: Mathias Thanks for the response!

Then is there any way to do this via powershell??